# Why would a DOM Document show as null when it is actually valid?

Tags: java, xml, dom

In one of my methods I have a DOM `org.w3c.dom.Document` instantiated and seems to be initialized properly since when I dump it using:

```
LOG.info("DOM: " + doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent());
```

It outputs a valid and current content of a SOAP message that should be there.

But only one statement before (and after), it shows as `null`:

```
LOG.info("doc BEFORE = " + doc);
LOG.info("DOM: " + doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent());
LOG.info("doc AFTER: = " + doc);
```

They both show `null` with totally **valid content in between**.

This doesn't make sense to me... What am I missing?

---

Update, per the suggestions in the comments: I changed the log statements to

```
LOG.info("doc BEFORE/AFTER = " + doc + ", " + doc.toString() + ", " + (doc==null));
```

And the output is:

> INFO: doc BEFORE = [#document: null], [#document: null], false

I therefore conclude that @qqilihq is right: The doc is not null, but doc.toString() is.

Comment: Obviously, the `#toString` method returns `"null"` (which does *not* mean, that `doc` itself is `null`).

Comment: `org.w3c.dom.Document` is an interface, so you can't have one instantiated. Perhaps whatever implementation you have is returning null? What happens if instead of `doc` in your log, you put `(doc == null)`?

Comment: That is interesting.  "doc" is printing as `null`, but `doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent()` isn't throwing a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: When you concatenate an object to a string, it automatically calls its toString() method, which may return null. What happens when you try to call doc.toString() explicitly? Is the result null?

Comment: ooh, @qqilihq has it I bet.  do `System.out.println(doc.getClass());`, then google the source code of the class implementing `Document`.  Then find the `toString()` method.  I would bet it's returning `null`

Comment: @corsiKa My implementation (some class factory) is not returning null. See update above. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet @qqilihq has the right idea.  Do a `System.out.println(doc.getClass());`, then google the source code of the class implementing `Document` that it prints out.  Once you find the source code, look for the `toString()` method.  I would bet it's just returning `null`.