# Dom Parser returns null

Tags: xml, saxparser, domparser

I am trying to parse a xml string, my xml looks like this:

```
xmlString=    <Resources>
    <Resource>
    <ResourceMatch MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:anyURI-equal">
    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI">http://medico.com/record/patient/BartSimpson</AttributeValue><ResourceAttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyURI"/>
    </ResourceMatch>
    </Resource>
    </Resources>
```

I am doing the following:

```
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));

Document doc = db.parse(is);
```

doc is coming null.

Comment: please post stacktrace

Comment: their is no error i am getting

Comment: I followed this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484921/how-to-convert-string-to-dom-document-object-in-java, even for this I am getting null

Comment: you are reading an xml from file ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would a DOM Document show as null when it is actually valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762244/why-would-a-dom-document-show-as-null-when-it-is-actually-valid)

Comment: @qqilihq even this simple hardcoded value return null: Document xmlResult = xmlArchitect.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("<root></root>")));

Comment: Is it a problem of jar?

Comment: @qqilihq I get the value if I do :doc.getDocumentElement().getTextContent();